# Creating a header in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Is this a valid way to create a header in react ?
as in adding the header constant the way i did.
I pointed to the line with a arrow.

```
const upload = (file, onUploadProgress) => {
    let formData = new FormData();
  
    formData.append("file", file);
    const header = new Headers(authHeader());
    header.set('Accept', 'application/json');
    header.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    header.set("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
  
    return axios.post(API_URL + "upload", formData, {
      headers: header,      <---- this part.
      onUploadProgress,
    });
  };
```

Comment: Your question includes axios. Try adding an axios tag to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed!

if you are using post man, you can even configure an instance of your API, providing it some baseURL and some other options, including these casual HTTP headers, and after that you are not going to repeat it in each API call:

some thing like below:

```js
// api.js file


import axios from 'axios'

const headers = new Headers(authHeader());
headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.set("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")


export default axios.create({
 
  baseURL: YOUR_API_ENDPOINT,
  timeout: 1000,
  headers

})
```

it also provides you some other customer stuff like timeour configuration!

more info you can find [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#axioscreateconfig)

Comment: any Ide why im getting this error.
has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: this is definitely related to your backend API provider developer, basically, they just disallow some origins to be reached to backend data and APIs, please check this with your backend guy :)

Comment: i am the backend and frontend guy :D its my project.

Comment: So in that case,  you need to add a `"Access-Control-Allow-Headers"` to your responses like this file here https://github.com/a-m-dev/NodeJs_Simple_Restful_API/blob/master/src/middlewares/cors.middleware.js

it's my node js template for the backend but this middleware is responsible for handling the CORS problem, which I think it's going to be useful in your case :)

Comment: That looks like something i need just dont know how to implement it in my case.

Comment: just basically copy/past it in your project, import it in where you instantiate your express instance, and use it like: `app.use(corsMiddleware);`

for more information check here : https://github.com/a-m-dev/NodeJs_Simple_Restful_API/blob/master/src/app.js

Comment: ill see what i can get done thank you a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231897/discussion-between-mr-gomer-and-a-m-dev).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see if you do not plan on changing the state of your header, you are doing the right thing. The header object basically needs to be an object.

Here's what the [axios API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#axios-api). It shouldn't change in react unless you want to do some state manipulation of the header object.